# Can I set two Content views in an activity?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new to learning android, and I am writing a program to show a point and its position(coordination) on the screen.

I use `TextView` to show the coordinates, and using `CustomView` to draw the point out.

Here is my xml.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/panel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_pointX"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="X : "
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_pointY"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Y : "
                android:textSize="24sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <com.example.pointnsendmsgtest3.svPaintCircle
            android:id="@+id/TouchView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp">
        </com.example.pointnsendmsgtest3.svPaintCircle>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my main activity of the code. I am just wondering that how can I display all the views in one screen.

There is only one view can be displayed on the screen, base on the last `setContentView` command shows in my script to the compiler.

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    private TextView tv_pointx;
    private TextView tv_pointy;
    private LinearLayout panel_touch;
    private svPaintCircle m_view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        m_view = new svPaintCircle(this);
        m_view.setOnTouchListener(new MyListener());
        setContentView(m_view);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public class MyListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
            testpoint(event);
            return true;
        }

        private void testpoint(MotionEvent event){
            if(!debugOn){
                return;
            }
            //initialize mXs and mYs
            ArrayList<Float> mXs = null;
            ArrayList<Float> mYs = null;
            if (mXs == null && mYs == null){
                mXs = new ArrayList<Float>();
                mYs = new ArrayList<Float>();
            }
            mXs.clear();
            mYs.clear();

            final int N = event.getPointerCount();
            float x,y;
            for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
                x = event.getX(event.getPointerId(i));
                y = event.getY(event.getPointerId(i));
                logd("x[" + i + "],y[" + i + "] = " + x + "," + y);
                mXs.add(x);
                mYs.add(y);
            }
            if(N > 0)m_view.setPoints(mXs,mYs);
        }

    }

    private final boolean debugOn = true;
    private final String TAG = "MyListener";
    private int logd(String msg) {
        int retVal = 0;
        if (debugOn) {
            retVal = Log.i(TAG, msg);
        }
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Here is the class how to draw the point immediately.

```java
public class svPaintCircle extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {

    public svPaintCircle(Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    public svPaintCircle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {super(context, attrs);}

    public svPaintCircle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {super(context, attrs, defStyle);}



    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        drawTouchPoint(canvas);
    }

    ArrayList<Float> mXs = null, mYs = null;
    private boolean mDrawn = true;
    private Paint mPointPaint = null;
    private Paint mRectPaint = null;
    private Paint mTextPaint = null;

    public void setPoints(ArrayList<Float> mXs, ArrayList<Float> mYs){
        if(debugOn) {
            if(mPointPaint == null) {
                mPointPaint = new Paint();
                mPointPaint.setAntiAlias(false);
                mPointPaint.setARGB(255,0,96,255);

                mRectPaint = new Paint();
                mRectPaint.setARGB(0x88,0x44,0x44,0x44); // 0x88 = 136 , 0x44 = 68

                mTextPaint = new Paint();
                mTextPaint.setTextSize(45);
                mTextPaint.setARGB(0xff,0xff,0xff,0xff);

                logd("init Paint");
            }
            this.mXs = mXs;
            this.mYs = mYs;
            mDrawn = false;
            invalidate(); 
        }
    }

    public void drawTouchPoint(Canvas canvas){
        if(debugOn){
            if(!mDrawn){
                float x,y,rx,ry;
                float dx = 80, dy = 80, r = 10;
                for(int i = 0; i < mXs.size(); i++){
                    x = mXs.get(i);
                    y = mYs.get(i);
                    //draw cross
                    //canvas.drawLine(x, y - dy, x, y+dy, mPointPaint);
                    //canvas.drawLine(x - dx, y, x+dx ,y, mPointPaint);

                    canvas.drawCircle(x,y,r, mPointPaint);

                    rx = x;
                    ry = y - 40;
                    if(x + 75 > getRight())
                        rx = x -76;
                    if(ry < getTop())
                        ry = y + 20;
                    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 320, 45, mRectPaint);
                    canvas.drawText("x: " + (int)x + " , y:" + (int)y, 0,35, mTextPaint);
                }
                mDrawn = true;
            }
        }
    }


    private final boolean debugOn = true;
    private final String TAG = "PointView";
    private int logd(String msg){
        int retVal = 0;
        if(debugOn){
            retVal = Log.i(TAG, msg);
        }
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

How can I make both `TextView` and `CustomView` shows together?

Comment: no, you can not

Comment: setContentView(m_view) not sure what you're doing here. You only have to set the layout as content view, it will automatically include any views it contains, custom and otherwise

Comment: you cannot set two content views in an activity. You already have svPaintCircle inside your xml file access it by findViewById and add touch listener.

Comment: consider marking my solution as an answer if it helped you out, happy coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, you can't. `setContentView` can only be done for one layout.

To add some value to my answer, I would assume your understanding of `setContentView` is a bit wrong. `setContentView` is how you tell android which `layout` file to associate with this activity (as per your example). that's how layouts with different components are done, it's one single file with multiple or different views inside one file (or being referenced from this file, with methods such as `include` in xml).

From the documentation:

> Set the activity content from a layout resource. The resource will be inflated, adding all top-level views to the activity.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(int)

Comment: Thanks! It helps me making clear about setContentView :)

Comment: no problem, consider marking my solution as an answer if it helps. happy coding :)